# fails to execute a query using Oracle ODBC

Tags: c++, oracle, odbc

I'm trying to execute the query "SELECT 1 from dual".
But after a SQLFetch nothing appears in ColumnData, herewith the memory is allocated and the function returns success. If query returns varchar type it works well. Just starting to working with the ODBC, im really confused becouse of  this ...

the code below

```
{
    bool isDone = true;     

    Connect();
    if(isConnected)
    {
        m_retcode = SQLExecDirect(m_hStmt, _queryText, SQL_NTS);
        if (m_retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || m_retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        { 
            m_retcode = SQLNumResultCols(m_hStmt, &numCols);
            if (m_retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || m_retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
            {                           
                for (i=0;i<numCols;i++) 
                {
                    ColumnName[i] = new SQLWCHAR[MAX_COL_NAME_LEN]; 
                    m_retcode = SQLDescribeCol(m_hStmt, i+1, ColumnName[i], MAX_COL_NAME_LEN, &ColumnNameLen[i], &ColumnDataType[i], &ColumnDataSize[i], &ColumnDataDigits[i], &ColumnDataNullable[i]);
                    if (m_retcode < 0 || m_retcode > 1)
                    {
                        ShowError(DESCRIBECOL);
                    }                   
                    printf("Column Name : %S\n SQL Data Type : %i\n  Data Size : %i\n\n", ColumnName[i], (int)ColumnDataType[i], (int)ColumnDataSize[i]);           

                    ColumnData[i] = new SQLCHAR[ColumnDataSize[i]+2]; 
                    switch(ColumnDataType[i]) 
                    {                       
                        case SQL_VARCHAR:
                            ColumnDataType[i]=SQL_C_CHAR;                           
                            m_retcode = SQLBindCol(m_hStmt, i+1, ColumnDataType[i], ColumnData[i], ColumnDataSize[i]*2, &ColumnDataLen[i]);
                            if (m_retcode < 0 || m_retcode > 1)
                            {
                                ShowError(DESCRIBECOL);
                            }
                            break;                     
                        case SQL_DECIMAL:
                            ColumnDataType[i]=SQL_C_CHAR; 
                            m_retcode = SQLBindCol(m_hStmt, i+1, ColumnDataType[i], ColumnData[i], sizeof(double)*sizeof(double), &ColumnDataLen[i]); 
                            if (m_retcode < 0 || m_retcode > 1)
                            {
                                ShowError(DESCRIBECOL);
                            }
                            break;
                        case SQL_FLOAT:
                            ColumnDataType[i]=SQL_C_DOUBLE;                             
                            m_retcode = SQLBindCol(m_hStmt, i+1, ColumnDataType[i], ColumnData[i], ColumnDataSize[i], &ColumnDataLen[i]); 
                            if (m_retcode < 0 || m_retcode > 1)
                            {
                                ShowError(DESCRIBECOL);
                            }
                            break;
                    }                   
                }                   

                printf ("Data Records\n------------\n");
                for (i=0; ; i++) 
                {
                    m_retcode = SQLFetch(m_hStmt);

                    if (m_retcode == SQL_NO_DATA) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }                   

                    printf ("\nRecord %i \n", i+1);
                    for (j=0; j<numCols; j++) 
                    {
                        printf("Column %S : ", ColumnName[j]);

                        if (ColumnDataType[j]==SQL_C_CHAR || ColumnDataType[j]==SQL_C_DOUBLE) 
                        {
                             SQLGetData(m_hStmt, j, ColumnDataType[j], ColumnData[j], MAX_LEN, 0);
                             printf("%s\n", ColumnData[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ShowError(NUMRESULTCOLS);
                isDone = false;
            }   
        }       
        else
        {
            ShowError(EXECDIRECT);
            isDone = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILED TO CONNECT");
    }
    Disconnect();
    return isDone;             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not looked at your code in detail but I can see some variables that are not declared. A select 1 from dual is probably going to return a column type of integer and your switch statement does not cover that. I'd suggest you add a default to your switch to trap column types you have not covered (which is good programming practise anyway).

Comment: All variables are declared in header. Select 1 from dual returns SQL_FLOAT, and i get to switch

Comment: But you bound the column as an SQL_C_DOUBLE and later try and call SQLGetData on it. All bound columns should be populated when you call SQLFetch. I a little surprised the driver even allows you to call SQLGetData on a column you've bound.

Comment: Also, you cannot expect to bind (or call SQLGetData) as a SQL_C_DOUBLE and treat what is returned as a string - it is not a string (it is a double) unless you bind it as SQL_C_CHAR.